# Arch Linux pacman -Syu breaks machine

Tags: boot, grub2, init

Strange things have been going on with arch recently after I installed libreoffice.

The first sign was that there were no longer any icons on my desktop. I thought this was strange so I rebooted, same thing. I tried opening chromium to google an answer but it would not open from the menu, I decided to then try running it from the terminal, and I got my answer...something like below:

```
Libicuuc.so:51: could not open file: file is not in dir blah blah
```

So, I looked around and it seemed that upgrading my whole system would solve the issue(pacman -Syu) and updated quite a bit of stuff, 231 packages. After I was finished updating I rebooted the computer, and now I get this error on boot:

```
Failed to execute init.
Kernel panic - not syncing: no init found
```

And then a couple lines of text, then a call trace. It stops there and can't do anything else. I looked around a bit before posting here and couldn't find anything that worked for me.

Comment: Chroot in and look at pacman's log to see what you updated. Deal with any *.pacnew files that were created.

Answer (score 1):

This warning typically indicates that there is a problem with your RAM disk. Given you cannot reboot, I would suggest you download and boot a recent Arch installer, mount your partitions (I think at a minimum you need `/boot` and `/etc`), and `arch-chroot` into your non-working system. Once there, you should be able to recreate your RAM disk

```
# mkinitcpio -p linux
```

You may need to configure your options by editing `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` before creating the RAM disk.

Comment: This did not work. I chrooted into the system and still getting the same output as before.